# ユークリッドの互除法でZeroDivisionErrorが発生する原因について

Tags: python, アルゴリズム

```
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

以下がコードです.

```
def Euclidean_algo(m, n):

    while m%n != 0:
        m = n
        n = m%n
    else:
        return n


m = int(input('the bigger int is :'))
n = int(input('the smaller int is :'))
print(Euclidean_algo(m, n))
```

Comment: タイトルには問題となっている事象を簡潔な言葉でまとめるようにしてください。また「初心者です」というのは回答を書く場合に有用な情報にはなり得ません。例えばコードのどこまでを自分で考えて書いたのかとか、どういった学習を経てここまで来たのかを本文中に含めるなどした方が、あなたの現在のレベルにあった回答を得やすくなるでしょう。

Comment: @tanalab2　　承知しました、ご丁寧にありがとうございます！

Answer (score 4):

私も一瞬ユークリッドの互除法を正しく実装しているように見えたのですが、実行してみてやっと気づきました。

この2行

```
    m = n
    n = m%n
```

最初に`m`へ現在の`n`の値が代入されるので、2行目の`n = m%n`が実行される時には`m`と`n`の値が同じになっています。よって、`m%n`の結果は必ず`0`になってしまいますから、ループの次の条件判定`m%n != 0`の中で`n`が`0`なのでゼロ除算例外が発生してしまうわけです。

単純に2行の順番を入れ替えると今度は`m`に入れるべき古い方の`n`の値が失われてしまいます。pythonなら同時に代入してしまえば良いでしょう。

```
def Euclidean_algo(m, n):
    while m % n != 0:
        m, n = n, m % n
    return n
```

こんな定義にして試してみてください。ちなみにユークリッドの互除法は二数の大小関係に関わらず働くので、`m`が大きい方の数、なんて指定は不要です。